# Enable PostgreSQL remote access- nothing seems to work

Tags: postgresql, centos, remote-access, iptables

I have tried everything I can find to enable to remote access to a postgresql 8.1 database on a centos server. I am trying to connect from my windows 10 PC using pgAdmin 3. I keep getting:

> The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports 
>   could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "server ip" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

This is what I have done:
pg_hba.conf added -

```
host  all all  "my public IP address"/32  trust
```

postgresql.conf -

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

restarted PostgreSQL

Added the following to iptables

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d "my IP"  --dport 5432 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -s "my ip" --sport 5432 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

restarted iptables

I have verified many times that I have the correct IP addresses everywhere.

Can anyone help with what I may be missing.

Update:
I stopped the iptables service and was able to connect so it is something with my iptable rules.

Comment: Did you configure Postgres to listen on port 5432? And why are you using such an outdated Postgres version?

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my post. Still trying to work out the editor. Yes it is listening on port 5432. We are converting/updating a very old system. I am trying to connect to the old server so we can convert the data to the structure of the new system. Then it's bye-bye to the outdated PostgreSQL version.

Comment: Copied this from the top of phpPgAdmin that is running on the server.  
PostgreSQL 8.1.23 running on localhost:5432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error with iptables. Using CentOS I needed to add
`-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5432 –s "my IP" -j ACCEPT`
Everything with the PostgreSQL was correct. Just needed to change the iptable rules per above.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to enable connections without password from other machines, in the line

```
host  all all  "my public IP address"/32  trust
```

`"my public IP address"` should be the IP address of the machine from which you attempt the connection.

Don't forget to run `pg_ctl reload` to load the changed configuration file.

To be promiscuous and allow passwordless connections from everywhere, use

```
host  all all  0.0.0.0/0  trust
```

If you encounter problems, set `log_connections` to `on` in `postgresql.conf` and consult the log file.

Comment: My local network uses `192.168.5.xxx` and my public IP is `107.xxx.xxx.xxx`. I have used both of these in `pg_hba.conf` without any success. I have being running `postgresql restart` after each change I make. I assume that would be the same as `pg_ctl reload`. I will try being promiscuous and open up everything to see if it works then narrow things down.